# Android standard font used to differentiate between capital i and small l

Tags: android, user-interface, fonts, textview

I have a textView in my android app.

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="@string/my_string"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Whenever I display string on this textView the **capital i** and **small l** looks same, Is there any standard font(without explicit user installation) that can be used that easily displays this 2 character differently?